# How to replace duplicate column values with blank without deleting entire row in MySql?

Tags: mysql, unique-key

I have a `mysql` table `contacts` as below

```
id  |      email      |   mobile    |
1   | abc123@xyz.com  |  9800000023 | 
2   | abc123@xyz.com  |  9800000021 |
3   | pqr111@xyz.com  |  9800000034 |
4   | pqr123@xyz.com  |  9900000033 |
5   | abc111@xyz.com  |  9804400000 |
6   | pqr111@xyz.com  |  9800500000 |
7   | abc111@xyz.com  |  8600000000 |
```

What I want to update duplicate emails values (except first occurrence) to either `null` or blank without affecting the `mobile` column.

The solution should look like

```
id  |      email      |   mobile    |
1   | abc123@xyz.com  |  9800000023 | 
2   |    <null>       |  9800000021 |
3   | pqr111@xyz.com  |  9800000034 |
4   | pqr123@xyz.com  |  9900000033 |
5   | abc111@xyz.com  |  9804400000 |
6   |    <null>       |  9800500000 |
7   |    <null>       |  8600000000 |
```

Is there a way to `IGNORE` duplicate email column value but `mobile` value should be insert into table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update contacts
set email = null
where id not in
(
   select * from
   (
      select min(id)
      from contacts
      group by email
   ) tmp
)
```

Comment: I am getting this error. 
`You can't specify target table 'contacts' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: That is because MySQL can't update a table it is selecting from at the same time. But you can avoid that with another subquery. I updated the answer

Comment: You need to order by if you care about the order things are blanked in. Like if you want all rows with a similar value together then just the first one blanked.